# Export to pdf using Python

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I have run this code on anaconda environment and it works well, but when I run this code on my Visual Studio App on computer, I have met a lot of errors such as: TypeError: FPDF.set_font() missing 1 required positional argument: 'family', multi_cell do not have argument "ln"
TypeError: FPDF.set_font() missing 1 required positional argument: 'family'. It is quite long, hope that everyone can help me, please. Thank you so much!

```
class PDF(FPDF):
    def footer(self):
        # Set position of the footer
        self.set_y(-10)
        # Set font size
        self.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
        # Add page number
        self.cell(0, 10, f'Page {self.page_no()}/{{nb}}', 0, 0, 'C')
    def create_table(self,table_data, title='', data_size = 10, title_size=12, align_data='L', align_header='L', cell_width='even', x_start='x_default',emphasize_data=[], emphasize_style=None, emphasize_color=(0,0,0)):
        default_style = self.font_style
        if emphasize_style == None:
            emphasize_style = default_style
        # Get Width of Columns
        def get_col_widths():
            col_width = cell_width
            if col_width == 'even':
                col_width = self.epw / len(data[0]) - 1  # distribute content evenly   # epw = effective page width (width of page not including margins)
            elif col_width == 'uneven':
                col_widths = []
                # searching through columns for largest sized cell (not rows but cols)
                for col in range(len(table_data[0])): # for every row
                    longest = 0
                    for row in range(len(table_data)):
                        cell_value = str(table_data[row][col])
                        value_length = self.get_string_width(cell_value)
                        if value_length > longest:
                            longest = value_length
                    col_widths.append(longest + 4) # add 4 for padding
                col_width = col_widths
                        ### compare columns
            elif isinstance(cell_width, list):
                col_width = cell_width  # TODO: convert all items in list to int
            else:
                # TODO: Add try catch
                col_width = int(col_width)
            return col_width
        if isinstance(table_data, dict):
            header = [key for key in table_data]
            data = []
            for key in table_data:
                value = table_data[key]
                data.append(value)
            # need to zip so data is in correct format (first, second, third --> not first, first, first)
            data = [list(a) for a in zip(*data)]
        else:
            header = table_data[0]
            data = table_data[1:]
        line_height = self.font_size * 2.5
        col_width = get_col_widths()
        self.set_font(size=title_size)
        # Get starting position of x
        # Determin width of table to get x starting point for centred table
        if x_start == 'C':
            table_width = 0
            if isinstance(col_width, list):
                for width in col_width:
                    table_width += width
            else: # need to multiply cell width by number of cells to get table width
                table_width = col_width * len(table_data[0])
            # Get x start by subtracting table width from pdf width and divide by 2 (margins)
            margin_width = self.w - table_width
            # TODO: Check if table_width is larger than pdf width

            center_table = margin_width / 2 # only want width of left margin not both
            x_start = center_table
            self.set_x(x_start)
        elif isinstance(x_start, int):
            self.set_x(x_start)
        elif x_start == 'x_default':
            x_start = self.set_x(self.l_margin)
        # TABLE CREATION #
        self.set_font(size=10)
        self.multi_cell(0, 2, 'Bộ Giáo dục và Đào tạo', border=0, align='L', ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size)
        self.ln(5) # move cursor back to the left margin
        self.multi_cell(0, 2, 'Trường ', border=0, align='L', ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size)
        self.ln(5) # move cursor back to the left margin
        self.multi_cell(0, 2, 'Địa chỉ:', border=0, align='L', ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size)
        self.ln(10) # move cursor back to the left margin
        # add title
        self.set_font(size=15)
        if title != '':
            self.multi_cell(0, line_height, title, border=0, align='c', ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size)
            self.ln(8) # move cursor back to the left margin
        tz_VN = pytz.timezone('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh')
        datetime_VN = datetime.now(tz_VN)
        # Lấy ngày hiện tại theo định dạng dd/mm/yyyy
        now_vn = datetime_VN.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        self.set_font(size=10)
        self.multi_cell(0, 2, f'Ngày: {now_vn}', border=0, align='r', ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size)
        self.ln(10) # move cursor back to the left margin
        self.set_font(size=data_size)
        # add header
        y1 = self.get_y()
        if x_start:
            x_left = x_start
        else:
            x_left = self.get_x()
        x_right = self.epw + x_left
        if  not isinstance(col_width, list):
            if x_start:
                self.set_x(x_start)
            for datum in header:
                self.multi_cell(col_width, line_height, datum, border=0, align=align_header, ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size)
                x_right = self.get_x()
            self.ln(line_height) # move cursor back to the left margin
            y2 = self.get_y()
            self.line(x_left,y1,x_right,y1)
            self.line(x_left,y2,x_right,y2)
            for row in data:
                if x_start: # not sure if I need this
                    self.set_x(x_start)
                for datum in row:
                    if datum in emphasize_data:
                        self.set_text_color(*emphasize_color)
                        self.set_font(style=emphasize_style)
                        self.multi_cell(col_width, line_height, datum, border=0, align=align_data, ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size)
                        self.set_text_color(0,0,0)
                        self.set_font(style=default_style)
                    else:
                        self.multi_cell(col_width, line_height, datum, border=0, align=align_data, ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size) # ln = 3 - move cursor to right with same vertical offset # this uses an object named pdf
                self.ln(line_height) # move cursor back to the left margin
        else:
            if x_start:
                self.set_x(x_start)
            for i in range(len(header)):
                datum = header[i]
                self.multi_cell(col_width[i], line_height, datum, border=0, align=align_header, ln=3, max_line_height=pdf.font_size)
                x_right = self.get_x()
            self.ln(line_height) # move cursor back to the left margin
            y2 = self.get_y()
            self.line(x_left,y1,x_right,y1)
            self.line(x_left,y2,x_right,y2)
            for i in range(len(data)):
                if x_start:
                    self.set_x(x_start)
                row = data[i]
                for i in range(len(row)):
                    datum = row[i]
                    if not isinstance(datum, str):
                        datum = str(datum)
                    adjusted_col_width = col_width[i]
                    if datum in emphasize_data:
                        self.set_text_color(*emphasize_color)
                        self.set_font(style=emphasize_style)
                        self.multi_cell(adjusted_col_width, line_height, datum, border=0, align=align_data, ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size)
                        self.set_text_color(0,0,0)
                        self.set_font(style=default_style)
                    else:
                        self.multi_cell(adjusted_col_width, line_height, datum, border=0, align=align_data, ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size) # ln = 3 - move cursor to right with same vertical offset # this uses an object named pdf
                self.ln(line_height) # move cursor back to the left margin
        y3 = self.get_y()
        self.line(x_left,y3,x_right,y3)
# def pdf(self):
pdf = PDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', r'ttf\DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font("DejaVu","",12)
pdf.alias_nb_pages()
pdf.create_table(table_data = data,title='Báo cáo', cell_width='uneven',x_start='C')
filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.pdf')
if filename:
    pdf.output(filename, 'F')
```

I run it on the jupyter and it works smoothly.

Comment: Did you check your python versions and package versions?

Comment: The difference is I use python version 3.10 and anaconda python is 3.11. But because of a lot of reasons 3.11 does not support features in coding app so i must move to 3.10. And now i do not know how to fix this.

Comment: For different reason I would recommend to use venv, there you haven't this strong dependencies (env creates for every project an own python instance), but if you want to continue with anaconda then try https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html

Comment: I think it can not solve my problem. Because in my project, I need Python <3.11 for other features and Python 3.11 for pdf, it's impossible to use simultaneously 2 versions of python in one project.

Comment: Yes, it is DEFINITELY impossible to use 2 python interpreter at the same time. So try to upgrade your features or use an older version of PDF